# Checking the left and right of a label with AWTRobot

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am currently using the Robot class to check the pixel color of the background of the frame, so that when my label (that is user-controlled) will stop when it hits a certain color (black). 
I have my code for the UP function (when the user presses the UP arrow key) here:

```
switch( keyCode1 ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            for (int i = thomasX + frame.getX(); i < thomasX + frame.getX() + thomasLabel.getWidth(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Color:  " + robot.getPixelColor(i,  thomasY+ frame.getY()));
                if (robot.getPixelColor(i, (thomasY + frame.getY() + 40)).equals(Color.BLACK))
                {
                    badMoveUp = true;
                }
            }

            if (badMoveUp == false)
            {
                thomasY -= 7;
                thomasLabel.setLocation(thomasX, thomasY);
            }
            badMoveUp = false;
            break;
```

How would I do this with left and right?